# C#でAWS S3に画像アップロード、URL取得

Tags: c#, aws, amazon-s3

アップロードは下記コードで成功しました。
アップロードしたファイルに
全員に公開と公開したURLを取得したいです。

公式リファレンスは英語で解読できません。
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

Google検索してもそのような情報はありませんでした。

```
using (TransferUtility tUtility = new TransferUtility("access_key", "secret_key"))
{
    TransferUtilityUploadRequest t = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
    t.BucketName = "bucket1";
    t.FilePath = @"C:\Users\a\Desktop\1.jpg";
    t.Key = @"1.jpg";
    t.Timeout = 60000;
    t.StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard;
    t.UploadProgressEvent+=displayProgress;
    tUtility.Upload(t);
}
```

Comment: 「全員に公開」というのはHTTPで公開したいのですか、それとも S3のAPIで取得できるように公開したいのでしょうか。

Comment: HTTPで全員に公開したいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アップロードしたファイルをHTTPで公開する場合は、S3バケットを「[静的Webサイト](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)」として設定します。※設定方法等はドキュメントをご覧いただくとして手順は省かせて頂きます

静的Webサイトとして設定したS3バケットは`<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com`というURLでアクセス出来ます。`<bucket-name>` は アップロードしたバケット名、`<AWS-region>` は S3 のリージョンを指定して下さい。

例えば、 US-East-1 リージョンの バケット名「mybucket」の「/hoge.jpg」ファイルのURLは `http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hoge.jpg` となります。

リージョンの名前はこちらの [ドキュメント](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html) を参照してください。

Answer (score 3):

.NET SDKのリファレンスは英語のみですが、S3のドキュメントは日本語になっているので、読みやすいと思います。以下のURLにC#でのファイルアップロード方法の説明やサンプルが載っています。

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html

S3 はパーミッションで公開する設定をするか、Bucket Policyで公開する設定をすれば、単純にURL指定でHTTP GETするだけでアクセスできるWebサーバのように動作します。公開されるURLがどのようになるかは、ドキュメントも参考になると思いますし、マネージメントコンソールでファイルをアップロードして、"Make Public (ファイルを公開)"をしてそのオブジェクトのプロパティでURLがどうなっているか確認するかでもわかると思います。

上記URLのサンプルでパーミッションを指定しているのは、
CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
の行です。